# Couting string occurrences on a table using Python

Tags: python

Assume that I have a table where I have a name and a value, like:

```
NAME       VALUE
Artur      2
Cristian   3
Artur      4
Peter      5
Cristian   8
Artur      2
```

I need to isolate the names and the sum of the values, like:

```
NAME       VALUE
Artur      8
Cristian   11
Peter      5
```

How do I do that?

I tried splitting each line to isolate the values, but I just don't know how to identify the repeated names.

```
data = open ('data.txt', 'r')

for line in data:
    value = line.split()
```

I need to group the repeated names and sum their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html), very powerful tool:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(fname, sep = "\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+")
by_name_df = data.groupby(by="NAME").sum()
print(by_name_df)
```

The first line will read the csv into a dataframe, with consecutive delimiters (if you have any whitespace and consecutive ones as well).
The second line groups by the `NAME` column and sums it, producing an output dataframe of the sums by the name.

If you want the names to stay a column and not be part of the index in the new dataframe, use this:

```py
by_name_df = data.groupby(by="NAME",as_index=False).sum()
```

Generated output:

```py
NAME      VALUE     
Artur         8
Cristian     11
Peter         5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict, the first time the name is met add it, otherwise add up the value. You just need to read the file normally, not forgetting to `strip` it and `split`, splits the string by spaces by default. Check out this code:

```
res = {}
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
  # Read file skipping the header
  for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
    name, value = line.strip().split()
    if name not in res:
      res[name] = int(value)
      continue
    res[name] += int(value)
print(res)
```

Prints

```
{'Artur': 8, 'Cristian': 11, 'Peter': 5}
```

If you want to create a new file with the result:

```
with open("new_data.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write("{: <11}VALUE\n".format("NAME"))
  for name, value in res.items():
    f.write("{: <11}{}\n".format(name, value))
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 10 seconds

Comment: Why work so hard to parse each line when you have entire libraries that do that for you

Comment: @Zionsof you can use any library you want, but maybe you simply don't, either you don't want to manage the requirement or importing a whole library just for one function? It's a solution, there are multiple.

Comment: While you're technically correct, my point was that giving a solution for a one-off is bad practice IMO. You'd want to have a general solution that applies for more than single function. Next day he'll add a column and the entire parsing needs to change.

Comment: @Zionsof That is for OP to decide, for this particular question there is no context, maybe it's just a short script, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to read this data with read_csv as;

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
```

it automatically change your data to dataframe format.

if it is in already dataframe format you can use pivot_table;

```
df = pd.pivot_table(data, index = 'NAME', values='VALUE', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `data.txt` contains this text:

```
NAME       VALUE
Artur      2
Cristian   3
Artur      4
Peter      5
Cristian   8
Artur      2
```

then this script:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    next(f_in) # skip headers
    data  = []
    for line in f_in:
        data.append(line.split())

items = {}
for name, value in data:
    items[name] = items.get(name, 0) + int(value)

print('{: <10}{}'.format('NAME', 'VALUE'))
for name, value in items.items():
    print('{: <10}{}'.format(name, value))
```

Produces this output:

```
NAME      VALUE
Artur     8
Cristian  11
Peter     5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = dict()
data = open("data.txt", "r")

for line in data:
    value = line.split()
    d1[value[0]] = d1.get(value[0], 0) + int(value[1])

print(d1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
data = open('data.txt', 'r')

summed = {}
for line in data:
    value = line.split()
    if value[0] == 'NAME':
        continue

    if value[0] not in summed:
        summed[value[0]] = int(value[1])
    else:
        summed[value[0]] += int(value[1])

print "Name\tValue"
for k, v in summed.iteritems():
    print "%s\t%s" %(k, v)
```

Outputs:

```
Name    Value
Cristian    11
Peter   5
Artur   8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to save NAME as keys and VALUE as values.

```
data = open('data.txt', 'r')
# skip first line
first_line = data.readline()

name_dict = {}
for line in data:
    value = line.split()

    k = value[0]
    v = int(value[1])
    if k in name_dict:
        name_dict[k] += v
    else:
        name_dict[k] = v

print(name_dict)
```

name_dict store value as:

```
{'Artur': 8, 'Cristian': 11, 'Peter': 5}
```